# incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm getting an error in this part of code:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment =new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

I get

> error: incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

this is the imports:

```
package liorsiag.lgbt;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

and this is the class title:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
```

No matter what I've tried I still get this error

I've tried a lot of navigation drawer tutorials, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: does HomeFragment extends Fragment ?

Comment: does `HomeFragment` extends `Fragment` ?

Comment: change from FragmentActivity to Activity.

Comment: Yes, HomeFragment extends Fragment and I've changed FragmentActivity to Activity, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: DrawerLayout also uses fragment, in your case it is using from support.v4 library, and you are also using Fragment of base android sdk (which are not same). Take these as v4.Fragment != android.app.Fragment

Comment: So... What to do, I'm new in this...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This seems to be an `import` problem.

When using `getFragmentMangager()`, make sure that your `Fragment` classes extend `android.app.Fragment` class.

If by any chance you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (see your imports), then you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. But I still have a problem now with this line: 
`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();`
It Says `Cannot resolve method`.

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` works if your `Activity` is a `FragmentActivity` if that is not the case, use `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Tried, yet this line:             `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();` does this problem: `Error:(191, 52) error: incompatible types: android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Make sure that `fragment` object is an  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and not an  `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: Made sure, didn't solve the problem... It says the problem is what shows the fragments in the activity_main.xml.
Any help?

Comment: Change this import `import android.app.FragmentManager;`to  `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Comment: Changed it but it says it can't resolve `getSupportFragmentManager()` in `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();`.

Comment: @zozelfelfo can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046175/fragment-cannot-be-converted-to-context-in-android

Answer (score 10):

Try changing

`import android.app.Fragment;`

to

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Use classes from that support lib for all other imports too. Also `getSupportFragmentManager()` as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

In your `HomeFragment` class

replace:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case i have changed line-1 with line-2

Line-1: `import android.app.Fragment`;

Line-2: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`;

Its working

Answer (score 2):

use `getSupportFragmentManager()` Instead of `getFragmentManager()`

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(in.jama.app.R.id.container, new Fragment())
    .commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

you just have to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; in the all the FragmentClass();.
that's it.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 2.3 getSupportFragmentManager works with  android.support.v4.app but android studio 3.1 you have to use getFragmentManager [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Pmz.png)

Answer (score 0):

import `android.app.Fragment;` works with `getFragmentManager()` method but before you have to remove the import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using support library, you should ensure to import both Fragment and FragmentManager from the support library. You will also need to ensure to load the support fragment manager.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
//other imports here...

public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_some);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new SomeFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i having same issue
so i updated

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
```

it is working fine now