# Issue with fragment transaction

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

```
package com.androidnik.tourguide;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MustVisit extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MustVisitFragment()).commit();
}
```

im getting this error : Error:(12, 80) error: incompatible types: MustVisitFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
 i have extended that fragment class within MyVisitFragment class and also have a empty constructor still im facing this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [incompatible types: HomeFragment cannot be converted to Fragment in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037662/incompatible-types-homefragment-cannot-be-converted-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: Did you manage to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is with incompatibility between `android.app.Fragment` and `support.v4.Fragment`. These two are not the same, and each has it's own `FragmentManager` they work with.

You are using `getSupportFragmentManager` which means your fragment should extend `support.v4.Fragment` (check the imports, and change to this). Either change that or get the other fragment manager by calling `getFragmentManager`.

I'd personally suggest working with the support library, since in one of my projects, it proved good to me, while I had various problems with the other one, but this is purely my opinion.

Comment: i have used the v4 import but i dont think its using the import as the v4 import is grayed out and alos i have set my min sdk to 23

Comment: That does not matter. Remove the `android.app.Fragment` import and leave only the `support.v4.Fragment`. Do this in your `MustVisitFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Replace android.R.id.content with R.id.container

Answer (score 0):

Add imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Will solve your issue.