# How to send data from listview from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, bundle

I have a couple listview items and I need when I click on particular listview to go to Fragment_2 with a value of listview that is clicked. I try code below on Fragment_1 I get the proper value an it show in Tosat notification, but in Fragment_2 bundle is always null.

In onCreate method in Fragment_1

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
                MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment ();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("view", value);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In onCreate method in Fragment_2

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String myString = bundle.getString("view");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), myString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**UDPATE**:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
                MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment ();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("view", value);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                            // ETC .......
            }
        });
```

Comment: add full code of setOnItemClickListener. So that I can check you are using correct method to replace fragment.

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: I have seen your code. You haven't use fragment. You opening new activity on click. So you won't get value on that fragment on other activity.

Comment: I open the other fragment from that activity

Comment: Then you will have to pass that data in new activity and then send it to target fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace below code in onItemClick method.

```
            String value = ((TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("view", value);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

On MainActivity replace your MainFragment like this,

```
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment ();
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            getSupportFragmentManager()
              .beginTransaction()
              .replace("your fragment container id here", fragment)
              .commit();
```

Comment: I get that error for `.replace(R.id.container, fragment)` incompatible types: MainFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski Please refer to the link, you will get your solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037662/incompatible-types-homefragment-cannot-be-converted-to-fragment-in-android]

Comment: Answer updated to support activity navigation with fragments. Please use that code.

Comment: in onItemClick method. I replace the code and I have error with intent     
`intent.putExtra(bundle);`
`error: cannot find symbol variable intent`

Comment: I solve it. I change `intent.putExtra(bundle);` to  `myIntent.putExtra("view", value);`
Thanks it's work now!

Answer (score 1):

you are not committing fragment

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
                MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment ();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("view", value);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

// This line is important
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the Activity "MainActivity.class" and passing your bundle to a Fragment class "MainFragment" but never actually starting the MainFragment.
So, it is obvious that your code won't work

Answer (score 0):

You are calling activity so how can you get the data in the fragment and if you are doing like this :

First you are launching the activity by this

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Then in this activity you are launching the fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace("your fragment container id here", 
fragment).commit();
```

Than in this case pass the data to the intent first like this

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
     myIntent.putString("data","Put the data which you want to pass");
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

and pass this data to the fragment by using bundles 
Hope it will work for you .

Comment: Can you explain a little more specific I don't understand what to change and where

Comment: Can you tell from where you are launching your fragment '

Comment: In MainActivity I have setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and I call the class in activity_main.xml with <fragment class="com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat.MainFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" /> and in MainFragment public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false); } I don't know it is right way I know a little for android

Comment: First replace your intent 
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
myIntent.putString("data",value);                   
 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);